# Index on a table that has 500 million records but no unique identifier columns

Tags: sql, indexing, key

How can I put an index on a table that has 500 million records but I dont have any unique identifier columns? I tried making a composite key but what would require me to include more than 3 columns just to make it unique and not have duplicates.

Should I create an identity key but that would give me a key value of up to 500 million so I'm not sure if its a good idea.

I can't partition the table either. So what should I do? Whenever i run queries against this table, it runs for a very long time and gets stuck even. Help!

Comment: The index does not require the values in the column to be unique, you can create the index on column with non-unique values. In this context, I do not quite understand your question. Perhaps when you write "index" you mean "primary key"?

Comment: I mean index. I should have reworded but arent indexes not so good when placed on a column with a lot of duplicate values? I want to place a clustered index but i have a lot of the columns having a lot of duplicate values. If i were to reduce the duplicate values, I would have to create an index on two columns but it still will have duplicate values. Is it better to just place an index on two columns to make it kinda unique or create a new identity value column?

Comment: Hard to say what would be better. Usually the index is used to optimize some query or queries. For one query the best might be one index, for other query the best might be other index. Please show the query/queries you want to seed up using indexes.